# Display just one infowindow automatically from an array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

I have a Google Map with an array of pointers and infowindows. I want to display a specific infowindow when the page/map is loaded.

How would I do this:

This is my code:

```
function initialize() {

var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.47921, -1.00201),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
map.setTilt(45);

// Car Parks
var markers = [
    ['location 1', 53.47921, -1.00201],
    ['location 2', 53.50726,-1.04641],
    ['location 3', 53.48313,-1.01016],
    ['location 4', 53.48197,-1.00954],
    ['location 5', 53.48319,-1.00842]
];



var infoWindowContent = [
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<strong>text 1' +    
    '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<strong>text 2' +    
    '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<strong>text 3' +    
    '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<strong>text 4' +    
    '</div>'],
    ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<strong>text 5' +    
    '</div>']
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });

    // Allow each marker to have an info window 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(13);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
});
```

}

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/OcuvuPI/2/).

I did some changes to your example

- styling was added, proper height and width
- initial zoom level was missing
- infoWindowContent is now just array of string and markup is corrected(`</strong>` was missing)
- LatLngBounds(): it needs SW and NE points. Changed to use `bounds.extend()`
- infoWindow is now created in a function called from `for` loop

Here is [the 2nd example](http://jsbin.com/OcuvuPI/4/edit) which opens the first info window on page load. You can change it to open any of them.

Comment: Thanks for the above :) Is there a way to have the first marker open by default when the map is loaded? Thanks

Comment: It has to be. But the code has to be changed a little to have saved all markers and infoWindow. And then attach `click` event to all of them and `load` to only one of them.

Comment: @user3022336: I changed the code so that markers and info windows are available in arrays for usage